# ¿Condicionar fecha automaticamente en una sola columna?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy realizando un formulario, para dar de alta un producto, en `mysql` tengo `id`, `sku`, `fecha_entrada` y `fecha_salida` y otras columnas.

Cuando doy de alta el producto solo quiero que se inserte la fecha automáticamente en fecha_entrada, estoy usando `NOW()` y si inserta la fecha y hora pero en ambos campos, tanto `fecha_entrada` como en `fecha_salida`. Solo necesito que se introduzca en fecha_entrada.

Gracias

Este es mi codigo para el alta de producto:

```
    $consulta="SELECT sku FROM movimientos WHERE sku='$sku'";
            $sql=mysqli_query ($conexion, $consulta);
            //mysqli_close($conexion);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) { 
                                             echo 'Ya existe la clave'; 
                                           }            
                else{

                      $sql="INSERT INTO movimientos 
                    (sku, nombre, descripcion, fecha_entrada, cantidad, costo, precio)  
                    VALUES ('$sku', 
                            '$nombre', 
                            '$descripcion', 
                             NOW(),                                                         /*Introduce la fecha y hora actual del registro*/ 
                            '$cantidad', 
                            '$costo', 
                            '$precio')";


                            $ejecutar=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
```

```
MariaDB [abarrotes]> describe movimientos;
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------------------+------------
----+
| Field         | Type          | Null | Key | Default             | Extra
    |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------------------+------------
----+
| id            | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increm
ent |
| sku           | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL                |
    |
| nombre        | varchar(25)   | NO   |     | NULL                |
    |
| descripcion   | varchar(100)  | NO   |     | NULL                |
    |
| fecha_entrada | timestamp     | NO   |     | current_timestamp() |
    |
| fecha_salida  | timestamp     | NO   |     | current_timestamp() |
    |
| cantidad      | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL                |
    |
| costo         | decimal(12,2) | NO   |     | NULL                |
    |
| precio        | decimal(12,2) | NO   |     | NULL                |
    |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------------------+------------
----+
9 rows in set (0.007 sec)

MariaDB [abarrotes]>
```

Comment: Deberias agregar la estructura de la tabla.

Comment: Puede ser que tengas un valor por `DEFAULT` asignado para dicha columna y por eso lo esta asignando; por favor muéstranos la estructura de la tabla con un `DESCRIBE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes un valor por defecto asignado a esa columna, con lo cual aunque tu no ingreses nada el sistema gestor lo hará por ti, entonces para quitarlo puedes ejecutar lo siguiente:

```
ALTER TABLE movimientos MODIFY COLUMN fecha_salida timestamp NULL;
```

Con lo anterior estamos:

- Modificando la estructura de la columna, manteniendo el tipo de dato (para evitar conflictos con los valores ya almacenados)
- Descartamos el atributo `DEFAULT` para no asignar un valor por defecto
- Colocamos `NULL` para indicar que si el usuario no ingresa una fecha, entonces quede un `NULL` como valor

Comment: gracias, solucione el problema.